# group by ID and delete the values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am modifying my description to make it more sense.
I want to select all the ID's which doesn't have value = Z2 ; How can I do that using sqlserver query ? 
below is the data example

```
PK ID    Value

1   1    x1    
2   1    x2    
3   1    x3  
4   1    X4   
5   2    X1   
6   3    z2  
7   2    Z2
8   4    X1
9   4    X2
```

Comment: What your actual problem?

Comment: You'll need to clarify if another value that would exist in group 3 should be deleted or not (ie are you trying to work row by row, or group by group?)

Comment: Hi Joachim , I am trying work by groups , I want to select the group which doesn't have Z2

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Since you clarified your question to just wanting to select the IDs that don't have `z2` as a value, the query gets simpler. Just select all id's and remove those that have a `z2` value using `EXCEPT`;

```
SELECT id FROM mytable
EXCEPT 
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE value='z2';
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5d82c/1).

(I'm assuming you want case insensitivity in this query)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table where value <> 'z2';
```

Answer (score 0):

You said in your question that you just want to select all the IDs which doesn't have value = Z2. So why would you want a `DELETE` query? A simple `SELECT` query like the following is supposed to give you the expected output:

```
SELECT ID 
FROM Table
WHERE Value NOT IN ('Z2')
```

From the query, you can see that I have used an SQL clause - `NOT IN`, which will exclude certain values from specific column(s) while retrieving from your table. You don't need a `DELETE` query to view those IDs.

For better understanding, please refer to this link: [SQL: NOT Condition](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/not.php)